# SQL query to find matches

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a query to provide matches with the same DB and it's giving me expected results except that I don't get few part of it. Below is the query :

```
select f.name, f.id, f.industry, d.name, d.id, d.industry
from product_table f, product_table d
where (f.name like '%' || d.name || '%') and 
(f.industrylike '%' || d.industry|| '%') and
```

I know by providing this it's actually looking for matches between the 2 columns :

```
(..... like '%' || ..... || '%')
```

But what does each part of it do exactly and what does it mean?

Comment: It searches for pairs of entries in product_table where the name of product D contains the name of product F, and the industry of product D contains the industry of product F. If there's a pair with the *same* name and industry, they'll show up twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is executing a self-join (here, a cross self-join) in which we query two instances of the same table for some purpose. In this case it looks like some form of data quality exercise, where we suspect we might have almost duplicate records. That is, we think we have records for the same combination of (product name and industry). The use of wild cards will identify records where the value of one column is wholly embedded in another column: for instance `'%STACK%'` matches `'META STACKOVERFLOW'`.

The posted version has a potential flaw, in that if there are two records with an exact match you will get two hits (one for F:D, one for D:F). You can finagle that by adding a filter on id

```
select f.name, f.id, f.industry, 
       d.name, d.id, d.industry
from product_table f, product_table d
where (f.name like '%' || d.name || '%') 
and (f.industrylike '%' || d.industry|| '%') 
and  ( ( f.name = d.name 
        and f.industry = d.industry 
        and f.id < d.id )
    or f.name != d.name 
    or f.industry != d.industry 
    )
```

---

The double vertical bar (more commonly known as a pipe) is the concatenation operator. It is used for joining strings together. (Many programming languages use `+` but Oracle reserves that strictly for arithmetic on numbers.)

> not so much clear on why we put it before and after only the second column : f.name like '%' || d.name || '%'

In this case, the query is concatenating a wild card. Given this value for `f.name = 'XYZ'` , we would get matches for  `'%' || d.name || '%'` on:

- `'1XYZ1'`
- `'11XYZ11'`
- `'11XYZ'`
- `'XYZ1'`
- `'XYZ'` <---- matching same record

We don't need to wrap `f.name` in wildcard operators because the query is a self-join so all the values of `name` will appear on the left hand side of the filter. When `f.name = '1XYZ1'` it match for  `'%' || d.name || '%'` on:

- `'1XYZ1'` <---- matching same record
- `'XYZ1'`
- `'XYZ'`

So you're going to get multiple hits already. Embedding both sides of the filter in wildcards will only generate more noisy duplicates.

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me more about the double vertical bar. I've searched a lot trying to understand it but not so much clear on why we put it before and after only the second column : f.name like '%' || d.name || '%'

Comment: Hello APC, another question if I may. Is there a way to kind of give precedence that results from first instance table better be containing some sort of ID. For example, if my DB has 2 kind of ID's (First kind always start with KD###### and the second kind start with DF######) and we're saying that I need to first map KD ID's with DF ID's but if both matches are only DF ID's then provide that too.. Do you think this is something possible?

Comment: Probably but that would be a new question. Please start a fresh thread. Remember to include sample data and show how the required output is derived from it.